# How to fix "TypeError: XXX.sub is not a function" when using jestjs

Tags: jestjs

I have a function

```
  UseMeToSub = (class: string, event: string, callback: () => void) => {
         ....
          return = class[event].sub(callback);
      }
```

which subscribes to any event in any if my classes. The function **works**.

I **need** to test this function.

my test looks like this

```
test.('UseMeToSub () => {
   // creates the class
   const classtoTest = initclasstoTest();
   const callback = jest.fn();
   //line 3
   classtoTest.UseMeToSub('someClass' 'SomeEvent', callback);
   .... more code;
 });
```

but the test returns with error at line 3:

```
.sub is not a function
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It throws you this error because the `class` argument is a `string`. Getting a value from the string by index (`class[event]`) will return you whether a `string` or `undefined`, but not an object with method `.sub()`

To fix this, you must pass the correct first argument to the method. Most probably it will look like that

```js
test('UseMeToSub' () => {
  const classtoTest = initclasstoTest();
  const callback = jest.fn();

  const eventName = 'SomeEvent';
  const classMap = { [eventName]: classToTest };
  
  classtoTest.UseMeToSub(classMap, eventName, callback);
  
  .... more code;
 });
```